# Invalid JSON primitive: columnName. jQuery Ajax to WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery, webmethod

I'm using jQuery Ajax to pass to ASP.NET WebMethod with this code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'Page.aspx/generateReport',
   data: {columnList:columnList, gridArrayList: JSON.stringify(gridArrayList) },
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   async: true,
   cache: false,
 });
```

**columnList** is a single string variable and **gridArrayList** is arrary of object like

```
var gridArrayList = [{id:1,value:"val1"},{id:2,value:"value2"},{id:3,value:"value3"}]
```

The WebMethod

```
public static void generateReport(string columnList, List<dataReportEpad> gridArray)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ExceptionType
"System.ArgumentException"
```

Message
    "Invalid JSON primitive: columnList."

StackTrace
    " at             System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

What you are sending is not json it url encoded form data, to send json you have to pass a json string as data.

```
data: JSON.stringify({columnList:columnList, gridArray: gridArrayList }),
```

Comment: I test this suggesstion but I'm getting the following error: ExceptionType
 "System.InvalidOperationException"
 
Message
 "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'gridArray'."
 
StackTrace
 " at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)

Comment: @omixam did you have `gridArrayList: gridArrayList` or `gridArray: gridArrayList`

Comment: I have gridArrayList: gridArrayList... This is a array of Objects and columnList is a single string...

Comment: @omixam Try using `gridArray: gridArrayList` since ` gridArray` is the  parameter name in generateReport.

Comment: I correct that already... But not work yet... The same error above... I believe that I can pass a string and array of object simultaneous... But I can´t....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

Javascript:

```
var obj = { 'columnList': columnList, 'gridArrayList': gridArrayList };
//where columnList is a string and gridArrayList is an array of objects

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'Page.aspx/generateReport',
   data: JSON.stringify(obj),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   async: true,
   cache: false,
 });
```

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string generateReport(string columnList, ArrayList gridArrayList) {
```

Comment: can you `console.log(columnList);` before your jQuery AJAX call to verify that it does in fact contain a legit string?

Comment: Yes... Before jQuery Ajax I get... the string that contain columnList...... ITEM, ID,QTY,Description,Availability...